# Azure Logic App to receive email with attached file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am using MSFT Logic App to automate a process.
Whenever a user uploads a file to Blob storage, I want to get a email notification with the attached file.
The part I have working is that I do get a email that the file is up. The part I don't have is attaching the latest uploaded file in my email to view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoAjA.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Get blob content` first:

[image]